# regex return string between quotes and exclude parts of string within brackets

Tags: regex

I’m a hack at regex. Been struggling with this one for a awhile and could use some help.

Here's the string I’m processing:

```
    "main title here [subtitle]" extra stuff here
```

And what I'd like to return:

```
main title here
```

I've been able to match the string within quotes but can't seem to *just* omit the 
string (and brackets) between the brackets when the match is returned. The following regex is where I currently am, but it will exclude the entire string if it contains brackets within the quotes.

```
"(\s*?.*?)\b(?<!\[)"
```

NOTE: I need to do this with regex alone. Maybe that's my problem...

Really appreciate the help.

Comment: Which lang are you running?

Comment: What's your output if the input is `"main title here [subtitle] foo bar" extra stuff here`

Comment: Also, do you need to cover the case when there is no subtitle?

Comment: `(?<=")(.*?)(?="|\s*\[)` will extract your example as given. But it won't work if there is text after the subtitle that needs to be captured. https://regex101.com/r/lT8yX8/1

Answer (score 0):

`/"\s*(\S.*\S)\s*\[/` works with your sample data.

For example, in Ruby:

```
re = /"\s*(\S.*\S)\s*\[/
re.match('"a title [a subtitle]" etc.')[1]  # => "a title"
```